# Async await foreach issue

Tags: c#, asynchronous, foreach, while-loop, async-await

```
    private async void btnLoadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if(AccountsFile.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
       {
           Accounts = File.ReadAllLines(AccountsFile.FileName);  
           foreach(string str in Accounts)
           {
               await LoadAccount(str);
           }
       }
    }
```

I've ran into a problem, I know how Asynchronous programming works it will wait for the task to be complete but LoadAccount() will never complete because it calls a function with a never ending while loop so it will not reach the next string in Accounts.

I don't know where to start with this problem. Any solutions?

Comment: Function with never ending while loop sounds like a problem you should start with.

Comment: The never ending while loop is important to my program.

Comment: Than look for *Fire and forget*: call your method but don't await on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of waiting for each account successively, you could wait for them collectively. This way, even if one of your accounts enters an infinite loop, the others could still proceed to load.

```
Accounts = File.ReadAllLines(AccountsFile.FileName);  
Task completionTask = Task.WhenAll(Accounts.Select(LoadAccount));
```

You would typically want to store `completionTask` in a class variable. Subsequently, when you break out of the indefinite while loop within your `LoadAccount` calls (for example, by signalling cancellation via a polled `CancellationToken`), you can use this `completionTask` to wait for all your tasks to complete.

Comment: The infinite loop is required for all of the accounts.

Comment: @Aidan: In that case, I would go with [MarcinJuraszek's suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26090002/async-await-foreach-issue/26090053#comment40882956_26090002): Keep your original code, but just remove the `await` (so as to make it "fire and forget").